# Spring Boot with Jetty+Jersey always shows 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jetty, kotlin

I have strange issue. I developed project with Spring boot 1.3.3 and modules mvc (excluded tomcat), jetty and jersey (JAX-RS annotations). My endpoints worked perfectly for running from IDEA and running assembled java - jar .JAR.

But then I tried to make my JAR executable with help of executable option in spring-boot-maven-plugin. My project still make correct requests if I start it from IDEA, but compiled executable .JAR always sends 404 error.

Ok, I maked some changes in JerseyConfig class. I replaced

```
packages(ru.finnetrolle.telebot.restful.JerseyConfig::class.java.`package`.name)
```

with

```
register(BroadcastResource::class.java)
```

and executable JAR works correct on my developer's PC. But when I try to assemble it on my linux server and add simlink to init.d - all endpoints again starts say 404 for all requests. I have 404 if I ask from local and from remote host. I also add

```
spring.jersey.application-path=/
server.servlet-path=/monitoring
```

into my application.properties file (I using Spring actuator as well) but nothing changes - All is working without and isn't working with

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also found an issue with description of my problem but no help https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3413

P.S. I'm using Kotlin, but this shouldn't affect this

Comment: So, I have a example. https://github.com/finnetrolle/kotlinrestdemo - this is a small example project with jersey via tomcat. If you clone and mvn install and run it with java -jar xxx.jar - you'll get endpoint at http://localhost:8080/greet/some.
But If you add executable = true in maven plugin like this
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
You'll have 404